# Unable to set page title in method

Tags: objective-c, ios, title

I am trying to set my page title in another method (instead of viewDidLoad). My code as follows.

Basically, the 'topicInfoLoader will be retrieving data from the server and passing it back to the app as an array. I used a NSLOG to verify that the topic's text exist. However, when I try to set the page's title in this method, it does not work i.e. page does not show title. Can anyone advise me on why this is happening and how can I resolve this?

```
- (void) getData
{
    //Get info regarding the topic
    NSString *topicInfoResourcePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/topics/%@",self.topic._id];

    Loader *topicInfoLoader = [[Loader alloc]initWithResourcePath:topicInfoResourcePath]; 

    [topicInfoLoader setCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *anArray){
        self.topicInfo = [anArray lastObject];

        //NSLog shows that topic title value exists
        NSLog(@"topic title :%@",self.topicInfo.text);

        //Set the page title
         self.title = self.topicInfo.text;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually set the title in my `ViewController`'s initializer and works fine.

Additionally, you are calling `self.title` from within an instance method that does not belong to self. I think where you are calling it from `self` is actually `topicInfoLoader` and not your `ViewController`. Or is `topicInfoLoader` your ViewController?

Comment: The instance method 'getData' belongs to 'self'. I am calling the completion block of another class's instance 'topicInfo'. In the return block, I can do various actions but it seems that the view controller does not recognize the setting of its title in the return block. Any ideas why?

Comment: Is `topicInfo` a property of your ViewController? Can you access anything from your ViewController from within that completion block? Why don't you just do `self.title` outside the completion block?

Comment: Cos the info I need is only obtained in the completion block. Since it is async, I am not sure when I will get it hence putting the self.title outside might not work at times.